# MongoDB - Query max date in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I've got a collection with a `registeredtime` field and to query the latest insertion:

```
db.orders.aggregate({ $group: { _id: 1, regt: { $max: "$registeredtime" }}})
```

Now I want to integrate this into a C# .NET Core MongoDB client but I'm completely stuck on this:

```
var filter = _collection.Aggregate().Group( _id => ???? )
```

How to query the max time of a field in C# MongoDB client?

Comment: Have you tried sorting by descending and picking the first value? Like: `.SortByDescending(x => x.registeredtime).Limit(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** With `BsonDocument`

```cs
BsonDocument groupStage = new BsonDocument
{
    { "_id", 1 },
    { "regt", new BsonDocument("$max", "$registeredtime") }
};

var result = await _collection.Aggregate()
    .Group<BsonDocument>(groupStage)
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Demo

[image]

---

**Solution 2:** With Expression

**Pre-requisites:** Create a concrete class for the output result.

```cs
class OrderGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Regt { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var result = await _collectionAggregate()
    .Group<Order, int, OrderGroup>(x => 1, x => new OrderGroup
    {
        Id = x.Key,
        Regt = x.Max(y => y.Registeredtime)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

> Demo

[image]

---

> Sample Input Data

```
[
  {
    "registeredtime": new Date("2021-01-02T01:02:03Z")
  },
  {
    "registeredtime": new Date("2022-09-02T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```